# When to use ASCII character codes?

Tags: html, xhtml, yui, ascii

I am using `&copy;` for the copyright sign.  What all do I need to replace on my web page with the ASCII character codes?  I also have '," on my page, do I need to substitute these also with the ASCII character codes?

Do I need to use the following when using ASCII character codes?  When would I use it else:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
```

UPDATE:

I am using the YUI API and they suggest that I use the strict doc type:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

How would this change now and what all do I need to represent the copyright symbol?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use `&copy;` if you're writing XHTML and you want to be able to process it in a non-external-entity-including XML parser, or in XHTML5 where there is no DTD to define the `copy` entity.

In this case, you might use `&#169;`, or, generally better, just paste the © symbol in directly and make sure you're saving and serving the file as UTF-8.

Comment: +1 for the recommendation to use UTF-8.

Comment: Where can I read more about this?  I need more info regarding this.  I'm using HTML strict.  I'm not sure when to use &copy; or &#169; and when or when not to use UTF-8, with or without these symbols.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing as the ASCII code for the © symbol, it is not part of ASCII.

Please see the [wikipedia page on ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) for details.

In my opinion, a symbolic name such as `&copy;` is always better than any magical numerical representation.

Comment: Then what is &copy;?  I thought it was an ASCII code representation of the copyright symbol?

Comment: @Brendan It's a HTML entity which causes the copyright symbol to be displayed.

Comment: I know it's the copyright symbol, I meant what is &copy?  I'm still not sure when to copy and paste the copyright symbol into the page, when to use &copy; and when to use &#169?

Comment: Please see my last comment to bobince :)

Answer (score 0):

The *U* in *UTF* comes from *Unicode*. In an HTML document encoded as UTF-8 you only **need** to use HTML entities when you want to insert a literal `<` and, depending on the context, a literal `>` or a literal quotation mark. You also **can** use them when you want to type a character that's not in your keyboard, such as ©.

Comment: Please see my last comment to bobince :)